# Finding PDF for random variable problem.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Two independent random variables are given; $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,16)$. Random variable $U$ has $U\sim Bern(0.9)$. Find PDF for random variable $V$, which is related with $U$ in such way that when $U=1$, then $V=X$ and when $U=0$ then $V=Y$.

I really have no idea how to start thinking about the problem.

Comment: You need to correct statement.  U=0 is condition for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called *mixture models* and have the form $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i f_i(x)$ where $\lambda_i$ are the mixture proportions ($\lambda_1+...+\lambda_n=1$) and the $f_i(x)$ are the densities from which $f(x)$ can be drawn.

Here we can use the law of total probability to get $$\begin{split}f(v)&=f(v|U=1)\Pr(U=1)+f(v|U=0)\Pr(U=0)\\
&=.9\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac 12 x^2}+.1\frac 1 {4\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac 1 {32}x^2}\end{split}$$

$U$ is called a *latent variable* in that we don't actually observe it.

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar idea but wasn't sure if I was right.